# Фильтрация содержимого

Tags: jquery, javascript

Здравствуйте! У меня есть вопрос.
Есть такой код:
`<textarea>бла бла бла <span>ро ро<span> бла бла бла <span>Роро</span></textarea>
<div></div>`
Как сделать, чтобы при клике на кнопку (любую) в div перемещался текст с *textarea* только со скобок *span*?

Comment: так?

     $div.innerHTML($($textarea.val()).find('span'));

Comment: Не работает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function() {
$('#mb').click(function(e){
    $('#ms').append($('#mt').val());
    $a = $('#ms').find('span');
    $a.each(function(index){
        $('#md').append($(this).text())
    });
});
});
```

В html делаем дополнительный скрытый элемент - буфер для содержимого textarea

```
   <textarea id="mt">бла бла бла <span>ро ро</span> бла бла бла <span>Роро</span></textarea>
<span id="ms" style="display:none;"></span>
<div id="md"></div><br>
<button id="mb">Бум!</button>
```